# Set environment variable - SETX

Tags: powershell

I need to set a system environment variable for Java. I'm currently using this method:

```
setx /M JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_17"
```

My question: Is there a better (PowerShell) way to do this?

I tried using:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("JAVA_HOME", "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_17")
```

But this does not produce the same result as `setx`.

Is there a better PowerShell way to set Java home?

Comment: Doesn't `setx /M JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_17"` work for you in PowerShell?

Comment: @VivekKumar It does, but not sure if there is a better approach.

Comment: One problem with setx is that the argument is limited to 1024 bytes. "WARNING: The data being saved is truncated to 1024 characters."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you try to set the scope?

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("JAVA_HOME", "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_17", "Machine")
```